# Convergence of a sequence of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a proof of the following fact:

The sequence of entire functions $\{(1+\frac{z}{n})^{n} \}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $e^{z}$ on every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

I don't know how to relate the sequence with the series expansion of $e^{z}$.

Thanks.

Comment: what´s your definition of $e^z$? some people use this proposition as the definition.

Comment: I'm defining $e^{z} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}{\frac{z^{n}}{n!}}$

Answer (score 1):

This is just an outline, which is too long for a comment:

Assume that the sequence converges uniformly. Then let $f(z) $ the uniform limit. Note that then $$ f^\prime (z) = \lim \frac{d}{dz} \left(1+\frac{z}{n}\right)^n = \lim \left(1+\frac{z}{n} \right)^{n-1} $$

(why?). If you know how to show that the limits $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n $ and $ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n-1}$ coincide, you may be able to conclude that this is true for the sequences depending on $z$. This way you may get $f^\prime = f$....

Comment: Thanks. I'll give a look at this approach.